# Game Center welcome banner not hiding status bar

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm working on an iOS game coded in Swift with Game Center support. Everything is working except that the welcome screen from Game Center isn't covering/hiding the status bar as shown below.

[image: currently what it's currently looking like]

But I want it to look like:

[image: What I want]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change a plist file:

- set Status bar is initially hidden to YES
- add a row: View controller-based status bar appearance = NO

Comment: Its like this in my project and sitll showing under status bar